# why this code is giving segmentation fault in gcc

Tags: c

```
void init(){

pre=malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
opt=malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
p=malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
prec=0;
printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n",p,opt,pre);
printf("Enter the infix exp\n");
fgets(p,50,stdin);
if(strlen(p)-1=='\n')
p[strlen(p)-1]='\0';
}
```

even though i am using pointer to input string. I have checked all the pointers against null

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `if(strlen(p)-1=='\n')`

Comment: Show the types of those variables, your input and the headers included in the program.

Comment: why malloc(sizeof(char)*50); ? 1 * 50 = 50.

Comment: please indent your code.

Comment: What line generates the segfault?  Is your debugger on vacation?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strlen(p)-1=='\n')
```

should be

```
if(p[strlen(p) - 1] == '\n')
```

This will check whether the last character of p is `\n` got from `fgets`

Comment: Remove the semicolon. And this will involve undefined behavior if `fgets` fails.

Comment: Mind you, this wouldn't cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @immibis ..but it would refuse to add a null instead of a newline.  Maybe this causes a segfault somewhere not in the OP's not-SSCCE:)  The OP doesn't even know which line is generating the segfault and is getting DCV for that no-debugging alone.